# jscrollpane scrollbar doesnt show in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jquery-jscrollpane

I made a simple jquery image loader and attached jscrollpane to it. It works nice in most browsers except in IE7 where the scrollbar doesnt show up. I cant find any solution to the issue. Anyone got any ideas how to fix?

[Click here to see the project](http://kumpan.se/temp/flickr/ex1/)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference after going over the code in the jscrollpane js file i belive it has something to do with this comment on line 92:

```
// TODO: Deal with where width/ height is 0 as it probably means the element is hidden and we should
// come back to it later and check once it is unhidden...
```

Looking at a solution..

Comment: Fairly certain this has been fixed/updated in their latest code release.